# How to store an array as a variable

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am trying to store a variable returned from php into a javascript variable how is this done??

```
 var array;
 function test(id)
 {
 $.post( "main/updater.php", { id:id } ).done(function( data ) 
        {
              array = data;
        });
  }
```

This works with a string but not an array, it stores nothing. The data is returning as an array but not storing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: don't confuse javascript with java...not the same at all

Comment: `"The data is returning as an array"` *No it isn't.* You cannot "return an array" from PHP to Ajax directly. You can only print it (echo it) out as some format like JSON, XML, or a list separated by some delimiter.

Comment: im returniing it as JSON sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in php:

```
echo json_encode($my_array);
```

in javascript:

```
var array;

function test(id) {
    $.post( "main/updater.php", { id:id } ).done(function( data ) {
          array = JSON.stringify(data);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$field_map = array(
    'element_3'  => 'Name',
    'element_2'  => 'E-mail',
    'element_14' => 'City',
    'element_15' => 'Country'
);

$submitted_data = array('fields' => array());    
foreach ( $field_map as $key => $label) 
{
    $submitted_data['fields'][] = array(
        'key'   => $key,             // e.g. element_2
        'label' => $label,           // e.g. E-mail
        'value' => $post_data[$key]  // e.g. john@example.com
    );
}
```